# Select statement in BIRT gives different (and wrong) output than MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, birt

I just started to work with BIRT today and I have no idea why this is happening.

I am using the example data from the BIRT Homepage with MySQL workbench.
What I wanted to do is, to show in a graph that displays which customer is the best one and payed the most money to me. For that I have to add all payments from customers together. This works fine in MySQL workbench, but the BIRT plugin returns wrong results.

I have the same SQL statement in the Workbench and in BIRT, but their solutions are different.

```
Select * from(
select sum(CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS.AMOUNT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT, CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERNUMBER,
CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERNAME
from CLASSICMODELS.PAYMENTS, CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS
where CLASSICMODELS.payments.customerNumber = CLASSICMODELS.customers.customerNumber
group by CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERNUMBER, CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERNAME
) as inner_table
where TOTAL_AMOUNT > 75000
```

In the workbench I get this as a result (which is correct!):
[image]

And BIRT gives this result, which is wrong:
[image]

It seems like BIRT does not add the values correctly when applying the "sum()" function? Could someone provide an explanation for this? Maybe I have taken a wrong approach for my solution? Again - I want to display a graph where I can see each customer (identified by his number or name) and how much he payed in total for all payments he ever made.

Comment: Don't know why results differ, but there's no need to use a Derived Table, simply do a `HAVING  TOTAL_AMOUNT > 75000` after the `WHERE` instead.

Comment: Btw, when I look at the actual data in the ClassicModels model, the BIRT result is correct, e.g. customer 112 has three payments: 14191.12
,32641.98
,33347.88

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the HAVING keyword, I did not know that exists. I'm still very new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was not connecting to the correct data source.
By default the data source connects to a sampledb from org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.sampledb.driver which I thought is already the one on that I configured in MySQL-Workbench, but it is not.

I configured the mysql.jdbc.driver and connected to my local database instead of the default one. This is working now and I get the expected results.